# Placement of "define" inside "lambda" bodies in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme

Does anyone know the rationale of restricting `define` forms to appear only at the beginning of a `lambda` body (i.e. not allowing them after any form other than another `define`)? To me it seems quite arbitrary and precludes from writing more elegant code. In particular allowing `define` anywhere would seem to eliminate the need for `let`-related forms, thus making code easier to read. One other benefit would be the disappearance of forms like `(define x)` (without any value specified), that only require a later `set!`, thus bringing together declaration and initialization.

Comment: I'm curious—what implementation of Scheme are you referring to with this question? I know Racket (including its R5RS implementation) allows `define` forms to be used anywhere in an internal-definition context, permitting interleaved expressions.

Comment: It's the standard itself that stipulates this. Yes, I know that there are implementations that do not conform to this requirement (BiwaScheme, for instance). _The <body> of a lambda [...] consists of zero or more definitions followed by one or more expressions."_ (<http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.3>) ``define`` forms are not expressions.

Comment: Hmm, you're right... looking through the specs, R[5-7]RS all mandate definitions be at the top. I'm guessing this is for simplicity since it allows the spec to make all internal definitions equivalent to a simple `letrec` (or `letrec*` in 6 and 7) form. This doesn't hold if you allow interleaved expressions and definitions.

Comment: No, I don't think that internal definitions can be equivalent to ``let``-type bindings, since ``define`` is a fundamental special form in Scheme, while ``let``-type bindings are derived forms (essentially, syntactic sugar for applied anonymous ``lambda`` forms).

Comment: @AlexM. local `define` != global `define`. A local `define` is syntax sugar for a `letrec*` where all `define` statements are in the same `letrec*`, evaluated in order with restriction on use until the expressions that are not `define`, which are placed inside the `letrec*` are to be evaluated.

Comment: @Sylwester: are you sure that they are evaluated in order? In principle, the point of the * in ``letrec*`` is precisely to escape the rigidity of sequential evaluation.

Comment: @Sylwester: are you sure that local ``define``s are to be implemented as ``letrec*``s? I agree that it is feasible, but is it stipulated as such by the standard, or merely an implementation choice?

Comment: @AlexM. In R5RS and earlier `define` are not required to be evaluated in order since they are transformed into one `letrec` while from R6RS they are transformed into `letrec*` which has all variables in one frame, but set!s them in order.The `*` only means variant so the different between `let` and `let*` (that `let*` is nested `let` with one variable each) is not true for `letrec` and `letrec*`. There is much confusion with `letrec` and `define` and #!racket (a similar language to Scheme) has different rules. It's a [paper on the subject](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/fixing-letrec.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are no reasons why an implementation couldn't support this. eg.

```scm
(define (fib x)
  (define (fin-aux n a b)
    (if (other-fun n)
        a
        (fib-aux (- n 1) b (+ a b))
  (fib-aux x 0 1)
  (define (other-fun x)
    (zero? x)))

; transforms into ==>
(define (fib x)
  (letrec* ((fib-aux (lambda (n a b) ..))
            (other-fun (lambda (x) ...)))
    (fib-aux x 0 1)))
```

This is a simple procedure. Imagine one with 10+ defines. It would be like a Scheme version of [Where's Wally?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where%27s_Wally).

When I learned Java in the 90s I was told to put all variables in the bottom of the class because it made the code clearer for the professor. I'm not doing that today but this question sorta made me think about how difficult it was to read code that referred to class variables I hadn't seen defined yet. If the placement of the expression was a matter of taste it might be more difficult to read Scheme.

Comment: Technically, I don't think that transformation would always be equivalent. Consider a non-function definition with side effects: `(define x (displayln "hello")`. If other expressions in the function also have side-effects, the reordering will become apparent.

Comment: @AlexisKing In R5RS the order of evaluation were undefined so the order of side effects were not specified. In R6RS you are guaranteed to be in order but all `define` becomes part in the same `letrec*` today. Perhaps the restriction guarantees you get the side effects in the same order as the code?

Answer (score -1):

Guile 3.0 relaxes the restriction of placing internal definitions in the beginning.

Comment: Many implementations may choose to relax many rules. I was asking about why the standard imposes a certain way of doing things that I don't understand.